# In recent tensorboard 0.6.0, how to show big image?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I've updated to the `tensorflow 1.3.0`, and the system updates automatically the `tensorboard` to `0.6.0`. But I found one question: in `IMAGES` for logging, previous version of `tensorboard` can show big picture for the image with `tf.summary.image('input', image_node, 1)`. But now in `0.6.0`, it seems the icon to enlarge the picture is missing (as shown in the picture).

Are there any improvement on this? It seems the picture shown in the div is too small. I want the image to show bigger. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found the answer:

There is a `show actual image size` in the top-left region of the page.

Comment: the image area has a lot of blanks. Is there anyway to remove the empty space?